# BSD Socket issue: inet_ntop returning "0.0.0.0"

Tags: c++, c, sockets, inet-socket

I'm trying to get the IP of the machine a socket I've bound is listening on. The port number printed works fine, but the address is "0.0.0.0". Here's the relevant code. `res` has been passed to `getaddrinfo` and `getsockname` before getting to this code.

```
char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
void* addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);

inet_ntop(res->ai_family, addr, ip, sizeof ip);

std::cout << "SERVER_ADDRESS " << ip << std::endl;
std::cout << "SERVER_PORT " << ipv4->sin_port << std::endl;
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An address of `0.0.0.0` means that the socket is listening on all addresses. A specific address like `127.0.0.1` would mean that the server is just listening on that address, but not on any other ones.